# RemoveAt on collection fails

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, .net-4.6

I have a Telerik Treeview control and I have add issues with the `RemoveAt(0)` when having 1 element failing to remove the item. How can this be even possible?

Here is an example of what I have:

```
- ParentNode
   |- child1
   |- child2
```

`TreeViewNode.Nodes` is a `RadTreeNodeCollection` object
`RadTreeNodeCollection` is a `NotifyCollection<RadTreeNode>`
`NotifyCollection<T>` is a `Collection<T>` (with notify property change interfaces)
and `Collection<T>` is the basic Microsoft collection

So this is a sample to explain what's happening:

```
// get parent node called "ParentNode" result is not null
var parentNode = treeview1.Nodes[0];

// get quantity of nodes result is 2
var qtyNodes = parentNode.Nodes.Count;

// try removing the first node : this calls Collection<T>.RemoveAt(T);
parentNode.Nodes.RemoveAt(0);

// here count is still 2

// removing the tag from the node which contain model informations
parentNode.Nodes[0].Tag = null;

// try removing the first node again
parentNode.Nodes.RemoveAt(0);

// now the count is 1 so the item really got removed
```

What does the tag have to do with `Collection.RemoveAt()`?
Also I have another case where removing the tag from the node does not work either. So what other properties to an object can cause `Collection.RemoveAt` to fail?

*** Edit ***
I simply replace all `RadTreeView` (telerik `TreeView`) and `RadTreeNode` (telerik `TreeNode`) by the standard Microsoft `TreeView` and `TreeNode` and the code runs fine so it's not the `Tag` property that is problematic.

Comment: the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/api/html/t_telerik_collections_generic_notifycollection_1.htm) of the `NotifyCollection` shows that it does not expose its own `RemoveAt`. But it exposes an index-based `RemoveItem` method. What happens if you replaced calls to `Collection<T>.RemoveAt` by calls to `NotifyCollection<T>.RemoveItem`? No offense to Telerik, but maybe it is just not implemented consistently.

Comment: `RemoveItem()` deos not exist for the object. Best i have are `Remove(Node)` and `Remove(String objectname)` and both are not working.

Comment: @Franck are you sure you are using RadTreeNodeCollection ? Because according to the  [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/api/html/m_telerik_wincontrols_ui_radtreenodecollection_removeitem.htm) there is one.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten it's private

Comment: You are right, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by changing the `RadTreeview` into a `TreeView` and all reference to `RadTreeNode` to `TreeNode` and it all works fine with the exact same code.